# Is it OK to ignore this debug error "[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid"

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am getting this error message when using a BT device in my app, the device works as expected and no problems at all communicating with it, all functions also works as expected so I am not sure why I am getting this message.

Can I safely ignore this or is it a ticking bomb that might bite me later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well… it is definitely nothing that you can do about. It's not a user error, so don't worry about it. Make sure though that you handle the state `CBManagerStateResetting`, which may occur when the daemon handling the CoreBluetooth subsystem has had severe problems and is being restarted.